# Access arraylist from another class without "return" Assert.fail(); unable to access return

Tags: java, arraylist, return, assert

I have read all similar question but nothing help.

how to access **arraylist** from another class without **"return"** 
Test Fail is not returning failedtest 
As I have Assert.fail(); under same method which I need return value.
Please help me find solution for if any alternative way to access arraylist .

```
public class FrontPage extends SeleniumUtils implements IHomePage {
public List<String> failedtest = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> CheckSummaryExposure(WebDriver driver, String actualView, String viewName) throws InterruptedException {
    String[] actualViews = actualView.split(",");
    List<String> views = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < actualViews.length; i++) {

            if (views.get(i).equals(actualViews[i].trim().toString())) {
                Add_Log.info("Successfully displayed " + viewName);
                Reporter.log("Successfully displayed " + viewName);
            } else {
                Add_Log.info(" filter criteria is not displayed " + viewName);
                Reporter.log(" filter criteria is not displayed " + viewName);
                failedtest.add(" filter criteria is not displayed " + viewName);    
                flag = true;
            }
        }

        if (flag) {
            TestResultStatus.Testfail = true;
// Test Fail is not returning failedtest 
            Assert.fail();
        } else {
            Add_Log.info("Successfully all filter);
            Reporter.log("Successfully all filter);
        }
        System.out.println("PRINT FAIL SENTENCE");
System.out.println(failedtest);
return failedtest;
    }
```

other class [Sanity_TC]  to call FrontPage class, method CheckSummaryExposure  with return failedtest

```
public class Sanity_TC extends SuiteBase {
    static public HashMap<String, String> Remark = new HashMap<>();
List<String> failedtest =null;
@Test(dataProvider = "SanityTCTest", dataProviderClass = utility.Xlsdataprovider.class, groups = "Dashboard", alwaysRun = true)
public void Sanity_TC015(LinkedHashMap<String, String> data) throws InterruptedException, SQLException {        
    String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();      
            loadWebBrowser();
            objLoginPage.login(getDriver(), username, password, URLs.get(Key), Instance);
            String result = String.join("-",FP.CheckSummaryExposure(getDriver(), actualViews, viewName));
            Remark.put(methodName, result);
```